# Any HTML entity would remove space?

Tags: html, line-breaks, html-entities

Due the change line would lead space between characters. I'm using `wbr` for stop creating space between charaters, like this:

```
<p><wbr
></wbr>这里有一段很长，<wbr
></wbr>很长的文字；这里<wbr
></wbr>有一段很长，很长<wbr
></wbr>的文字；这里有一<wbr
></wbr>段很长，很长的文<wbr
></wbr>字；</p>
```

I just wonder if there is a better solution? Maybe... is there any HTML entity could remove all front space?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do... The `<wbr>` element is designed to tell the browser where it's OK to break a word - it's official name is Word Break Opportunity. It does not insert breaks... See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr
By the way, it does not have a closing `</wbr>` tag!

Comment: I think using a comment `<!--`,  `-->` is more common practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML entities are used to represent reserved characters like angle brackets.

One objective of web development is to separate style from structure from presentation. That's why this problem must be solved with JavaScript, not HTML.

To do it, you would simply select the element from the DOM and use the `replace` method. To replace all instances of whitespace do the following

```
var wbr = document.getElementsByTagName("wbr");
wbr.innerHTML = wbr.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

To replace only leading and trailing whitespace do this

```
wbr.innerHTML = wbr.innerHTML.trim();
```